Relationship between median and mean of a left skewed distribution
Question
If I see graphically that my distribution is left-skewed. How to concretely (still qualitatively) conclude that the Mean is less than the Median? At least in nonpathological examples?
There is a possible duplicate, but the accepted answer or other answers there didn't solve my doubt, infact they were focused on saying, this statement isn't true in the most general setting.
Thoughts
When I try to look it up, I always find one argument saying that since the data is left-skewed, the tail goes far left, and some outliers will bring down the mean more than the median. But that sounds like just a restatement of my doubt. Why, if the mean is brought down, it gets below the median?
